# Multiprocessing Manager failing on very simple example with pool.apply_async

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm seeing some unexpected behavior in my code related to python `multiprocessing`, and the `Manager` class in particular. I wrote out a super simple example to try and better understand what's going on:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from collections import defaultdict


def process(d):
    print('doing the process')
    d['a'] = []
    d['a'].append(1)
    d['a'].append(2)


def main():
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict({'c': 2})
        result = pool.apply_async(process, args=(d))
        print(result.get())

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        print(d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This fails, and the stack trace printed from `result.get()` is as follows:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "<string>", line 2, in __iter__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 825, in _callmethod
    proxytype = self._manager._registry[token.typeid][-1]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_registry'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mp_test.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "mp_test.py", line 25, in main
    print(result.get())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_registry'
```

I'm still unclear on what's happening here. This seems to me to be a very, very straightforward application of the Manager class. It's nearly a copy of the actual [example used in the official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), with the only difference being that i'm using a pool and running the process with apply_async. I'm doing this because that's what i'm using in my actual project.

To clarify, I wouldn't get a stack trace if I didn't have the `result =`  and `print(result.get())` in there. I just see `{'c': 2}` printed when I run the script, which indicated to me that something was going wrong and wasn't being shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things to start with:  first, this isn't the code you ran. The code you posted has

```
  result = pool.apply_async(process2, args=(d))
```

but there is no `process2()` defined.  Assuming "process` was intended, the next thing is the

```
args=(d)
```

part. That's the same as typing

```
args=d
```

but that's not what's *needed*. You need to pass a sequence of the intended arguments. So you need to change that part to

```
args=(d,) # build a 1-tuple
```

or

```
args=[d]  # build a list
```

Then the output changes, to

```
{'c': 2, 'a': []}
```

Why aren't 1 and 2 in the the 'a' list?  Because it's only the dict itself that lives on the manager server.

```
d['a'].append(1)
```

first gets the mapping for 'a' from the server, which is an empty list. But that empty list is not shared in any way - it's local to `process()`. You append 1 to it, and then it's thrown away - the server knows nothing about it. Same thing for 2.

To get what you want, you need to "do something" to tell the manager server about what you changed; e.g.,

```
d['a'] = L = []
L.append(1)
L.append(2)
d['a'] = L
```

Comment: good catch, yes, I did mean to write 'process' - this is a very slightly stripped down version of the code that i'm running, cleaned up for viewing instead of having a bunch of my test stuff lying around unorganized.

Comment: could you elaborate on the "do something" - not sure how what you wrote gets around the issue

Comment: Your `append` calls work _only_ on the list, which doesn't involve the dict at all. Storing into `d[`a`]` forces `d.__setitem__` to get called, which is delegated to the server to perform.  Under the covers, `L` is pickled and sent to the server too, so the server can complete the `__setitem__` action.

Comment: I see. Thanks so much!